# How should I get hash defined as enumerize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use enumerize in my rails project like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Enumerize

  enumerize :sex, in: {
    male: 0,
    female: 1,
    other: 2,
  }, predicates: { prefix: false }

...

end
```

Now I want to get the hash passed to the enumerize with `in:`, so that I can use the pairs of the values and ints on the view file. (I know we should have stored them as a table in DB, not enumerize. But we can't change it right now)

I found `User.sex.values()` returns a list like `["male", "female", "other]`. But Can I get the hash itself?

Comment: `User.sex.options` https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize#usage

Comment: But I would go with the built in [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) which has a much simpler or at least more logical API.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using active record you should be [using](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

You would be able to call User.sexes to get the key value pairs.

I am not sure why you are looking to use Enumerize.